# strtok into character arrays not working as expected

Tags: c, strtok

I am quite new to C programming and and currently struggling with strtok. I want to split a string into two strings using the following code (the string is e.g. "Bat1:185", the delimiter is the colon):

```
char batName[13];
char batVoltage[3];
char *result = NULL;

result = strtok(pStringToSplit, pDelimiter);
strcpy(batName, result);

result = strtok(NULL, pDelimiter);
strcpy(batVoltage, result);
```

After the first strtok call batName contains the value ("Bat1") as expected, but after the second strtok batName is empty, batVoltage contains the correct value "185".

I know that this code is very weak, but currently I am just trying to understand the basics of strtok. I have already spent a lot of time looking for a solution to this, but could not find any.

Thanks a lot for any hints
Peter

Answer (score 2):

The value `185` is terminated by a nul (\0) character and really takes 4 characters of space. Your `nul` is written outside the buffer, seemingly overwriting the first character in `batName` with a string terminator.

Strictly, overwriting a buffer is undefined behavior, so this code could really behave in any way, depending on the compiler.

Comment: Excellent, that was it, thank you both a lot for your very fast help! Program is running now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a buffer overflow in your code. Remember that the destination string arrays need an extra character for the terminating `'\0'` character. That means that when you get the second sub-string you overwrite the `batVoltage` array and apparently into the `batName` array.

Increase the size of the `batVoltage` array by one and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As pinted out by Joachim you have a buffer overflow for voltage, as its of three characters `185`, the destination needs an extra space for NULL (`\0`).

So,

```
int main ()
{
char batName[13]; // Battery Identifier must be <=12, 1 for NULL
char batVoltage[3+1]; //Increase size, not just 4, but max digits of volatage+1
char *result = NULL;

char pStringToSplit[] ="Bat1:185";
const char *pDelimiter=":";

result = strtok(pStringToSplit, pDelimiter);
strcpy(batName, result);

result = strtok(NULL, pDelimiter);
strcpy(batVoltage, result);

printf("Battery :%s  Voltage:%s ",batName,batVoltage);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/joachim-pileborg) and [Joachim Isaksson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477878/joachim-isaksson) answered, You will hit `Buffer Overflow` here. Going forward if you fix this issue and according to your string (if it is like this `Bat1:185:Bat2:186:Bat3:187`) You can do some mathematics stuff to tokenize this string.

`After the first strtok call batName contains the value ("Bat1") as expected, but after the second strtok batName is empty, batVoltage contains the correct value "185".`

Here you can easily check that after every odd call you will get `Bat*` and every even call you will get `18*`.

I hope this will also help you.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, much appreciated. Increasing the size of batVoltage by 1 solved the problem.